# LXDE/LXQT distro with 5 years support?

Tags: distribution-choice, lxde, support-cycle, distributions

Does a distro exist based on (pre-installed) LXDE/LXQT which has 5 years support minimum. I have seen Lubuntu which only has 3 years support.

I am basically looking for a very stable desktop distro which is not a rolling release distro which has predictable scheduled releases every 5 years or more.

Comment: Peppermint OS 5 has LXDE and 5 year support.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with CentOS 7, which will be supported for ten years. You can install LXDE/LXQT on it. The other option is Debian 7, but for now it's not clear for how long it's going to be supported.

Long support extends the period of software maintenance; it also alters the type and frequency of software updates (patches) to reduce the risk, expense, and disruption of software deployment, while promoting the dependability of the software. This mostly applies to security updates. While in theory developers could backport just the security fixes from each new release to their deployed version, in practise this would often be prohibitively difficult or costly. There is a moment when backporting costs more than new deployment. So, if you really want a stable release for a very long time, go with servers distros like debian or centos - in enterprise, deployment of new version is very expensive, and because of that support is longer. And for regular user proportion of cost/risks is lower, that's why support is shorter.

Comment: I should have made my question clearer, which I have now.  When I said "based on LXDE", I meant a distro which has LXDE pre installed.  I understand it's not complicated to install LXDE, but I find it difficult to get a consistent theme with LXDE if installed later on into a disto which doesn't have it pre installed.  Based on past releases, debian seems to support each release for roughly 3 years.

Comment: No, Debian 6 was released in 2011 and will be supported till 2016. It depends on developer's decision. Actually, non-rolling distro will be completely deprecated in 5 years, do you really need such long support?

Comment: > non-rolling distro will be completely deprecated in 5 years.

What do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited my answer with explanation about maintenance and support.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the solution. Choose Lubuntu LTS (Long Term Support), that's

1. 14.04.5 supported until 2019-04 (another 3 years) or
2. 16.04.1 supported until 2021-04 (another 5 years)

Ubuntu, and its derivatives, have LTS releases every 2 years.
This of course applies for **LXDE alone**. LxQt, while very interesting, is still WiP and getting real support for it could be rather hard.
LxQt hasn't seen a new release since November 2, 2015 and it was v0.10.